# Chrome password autofill issue - password does not automatically get filled on certain URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, autofill, password-autofill

I have a web application (react based) deployed on multiple environments (test, stage, dev, production - only the URLs are different, application code is exactly the same and each url has saved username and passwords). On landing page a password field opens up in a modal. Now there's this strange issue with chrome wherein it automatically pre fills the password on only one environment. In the other environment it will not fill up the password till I focus on that field - once focused, it will show up the saved passwords prompt to select a password from.

Has anyone encountered such an issue before? What could be the possible reason for it / direction to look into?

I have tried the below things:

- Compared HTML - no difference
- Compared domains - the environments have *.com domains so no difference there, same SSL certificate
- Locally simulate exact domain name - no luck
- Number of saved passwords - compared these as well - nothing out of ordinary

but have not been able to figure out any possible difference which could be driving this difference in behaviour.

I want that the behaviour should be consistent - if the password autofills, it should autofill on all envs, else not.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "environment"?

Comment: I mean deployment on specific URLs, example: test, dev, stage, production and so on - except for the slight change in url, there is no other difference and all of them have saved passwords

Comment: And you're expecting Chrome to fill in a password saved for one domain in a page served by a different domain?

Comment: All of the urls have a username/password saved for them.

In one environment - chrome autofills the password as soon as I land on the page i.e. the page gets loaded.

In all other environments - chrome does not do that, instead it waits for me to focus on the password field and shows a prompt with saved passwords to fill in

Comment: Ah, so you've got the passwords separately saved for each different domain, OK thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding these attributes to your `<input/>`

1. `name="password"`
2. `autofill="enabled"`

Also check if there is a `<form>` tag around your form

Comment: These things are added and are identical across all the urls - yet, the autofill happens only on one url

Comment: Take a look at chrome://settings/passwords maybe your domains was excluded